# Ticker for unanswered questions of my favorite tags

Tags: feature-request

Is there some way to get **instant**, ticker-like notifications when a question that has a specific tag has just been posted? So I can answer quickly.

There would be several solutions to this, e.g.:

- When I have this something like this
  open in my browser:
  h[ttp://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/wpf)
  make the site update itself
  automatically. Just as it updated
  automatically when I am in the
  process of posting an answer.
- Allow me to subsribe with twitter for certian tags.
- have an extra desktop ticker app

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options for that.  First, you could hook the RSS feed for a tag up to Twitter via a free service like [TwitterFeed](http://twitterfeed.com/).  Second you could create a room in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms) that follows a tag and get instant updates in the chat room.